# What does `{ _?:never }` do?

Tags: typescript

I am reading some TypeScript code and encounter a problem. For this code:

```js
type LiteralUnion<T extends U, U extends Primitive> =
  | T
  | (U & { _?: never });
```

What does LiteralUnion do and what does the `U & { _?: never }` part mean?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `_` is just a convention and you can change it to whatever you want as long as the name is not reserved in JavaScript.

Look at the snippet below:

```
type LiteralUnion<T extends U, U extends {}> =| T| (U & {});

type MyObject = LiteralUnion<'hi', {}> | { test: string }

const myObj: MyObject = { test: 'test', color: 'red' };
```

the snippet will compile because `{}` allows everything on the object. Here we use `_?: never` to avoid such conflicts so that you will not be able to pass `color: 'red'` in the example above also, you can not assign any value to `_`. You can change `_` to whatever you want as it is only a convention which means there should be no arguments.

So this one will not compile:

```
type LiteralUnion<T extends U, U extends {}> =| T| (U & {_?: never}); //_? or name? make no difference.

type MyObject = LiteralUnion<'hi', {}> | { test: string }

const myObj: MyObject = { test: 'test', color: 'red' };
```